# how do I get the switch command to work if the field is empty to return n/a

Tags: php

Hello I wrote the following code but I'm having a small problem.

In my data base I have a field called `gf_gemstone`  I wrote a switch script (below)

The last part I want to write if the field is `empty` to return `N/A`. But no matter what I do I can't get it to work.  Can any body help.

```
 case "gf_gemstone_Amazon1a":
            switch ($value) {
                case "Agate":
                    return "agate";
                    break;
                case "Amethyst":
                    return "amethyst";
                    break;
                case "Aquamarine":
                    return "aquamarine";
                    break;
                case "Black Diamond":
                    return "black-diamond";
                    break;
                case "Black Sapphire":
                    return "sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Blue Diamond":
                    return "blue-diamond";
                    break;
                case "Blue Sapphire":
                    return "blue-sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Blue Topaz":
                    return "blue-topaz";
                    break;
                case "Chalcedony":
                    return "chalcedony";
                    break;
                case "Citrine":
                    return "citrine";
                    break;
                case "Cognac Diamond":
                    return "brown-diamond";
                    break;
                case "Diamond":
                    return "diamond";
                    break;
                case "Emerald":
                    return "emerald";
                    break;
                case "Garnet":
                    return "garnet";
                    break;
                case "Green Amethyst":
                    return "green-quartz";
                    break;
                case "Green Quartz":
                    return "green-quartz";
                    break;
                case "Green Sapphire":
                    return "green-sapphire ";
                    break;
                case "Lemon Quartz":
                    return "lemon-quartz";
                    break;
                case "Morganite":
                    return "morganite";
                    break;
                case "Multi Sapphire":
                    return "sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Onyx":
                    return "onyx";
                    break;
                case "Opal":
                    return "opal";
                    break;
                case "Orange Sapphire":
                    return "sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Peridot":
                    return "peridot";
                    break;
                case "Pink Sapphire":
                    return "pink-sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Pink Sapphire":
                    return "pink-sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Pink Topaz":
                    return  "pink-topaz";
                    break;
                case "Pink Tourmaline":
                    return "pink-tourmaline";
                    break;
                case "Quartz":
                    return "quartz";
                    break;
                case "Rose Quartz":
                    return "rose-quartz";
                    break;
                case "Rhodolite Garnet":
                    return "rhodolite-garnet";
                    break;
                case "Ruby":
                    return "ruby";
                    break;
                case "Sapphire":
                    return "sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Smokey Quartz":
                    return "smoky-quartz";
                    break;
                case "Spessartite":
                    return "spessartite-garnet";
                    break;
                case "Tanzanite":
                    return "tanzanite";
                    break;
                case "Tsavorite":
                    return "tsavorite";
                    break;
                case "Turquoise":
                    return "turquoise";
                    break;
                case "White Sapphire":
                    return "sapphire";
                    break;
                case "Yellow Diamond":
                    return "yellow-diamond";
                    break;
                case "Yellow Sapphire":
                    return "sapphire";
                    break;
                        case "":
                    return "N/A";
                    break;
              default: return "";
            }
            break;
```

Comment: What about `default: return "N/A";`?

Comment: by the way: you don't need a `break` after `return` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it far more compactly as:

```
$stones = array('Agate' => 'agate', 'Amethyst' => 'amethyst', etc...);
if (in_array($value, array_keys($stones))) {
   return $stones[$val];
} else {
   return "N/A";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MarcB's answer is more precise but still, if you would like to go with `switch ... case`,  use it like this for `NULL` values:

```
case (NULL === $value):
    return "N/A";
```